# Looping through all combinations of dataframes to apply a function between them

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop, combinations

I have 6 matrices (but they are allowed to be data frames if that's easier).

I would like to perform statistical tests on all possible combinations of data frames/matrices. I prefer a "for-loop", but any `apply` function is welcome as well.

Let's say the `t.test(x,y)` function.

So: t.test(1,2), t.test(1,3), ....., t.test(5,6)

I have placed all data frames in a list and used `combn()` to produce all possible combinations.

From here I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Try `combn(x, y, FUN = function(x) t.test(x[[1]], x[[2]])$p.value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make use of the `FUN` parameter from `combn`

```
lstOut <- combn(x, y, FUN = function(x) list(t.test(x[[1]], x[[2]])))
names(lstOut) <- combn(names(x), y, FUN = paste, collapse="_")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. Is there a way to keep track of which output is a result of which combination? My matrices have names.

Comment: @RoddyMacintyre  Sure you can create a names based on the names of 'x', i.e. `combn(names(x), y, FUN = paste, collapse="_")` and then assign that as names of 'lstOut'